# Lightweight Migration hassle iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, migration

i am having a bit of a hassle, i created a new version of my context & made it the default one,
after that i changed my code according to the apple docs and it looks like that now:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = persistentStoreCoordinator;
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];


    BOOL success = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                     configuration:nil URL:storeURL
                                           options:options error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved Error");
        abort();
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

but i get an error even though it is 1:1 the same code, in the line `BOOL sucess` i get an `incompatible pointer to integer conversion 'BOOL'  with 'NSPersistentstore'`

somehow the mapping has worked though and i get the new model in lets say 4 out of 5 times it works, the 5th it throws an error in that line.

any ideas how to fix it?

**UPDATE** i changed the code a bit and it now looks like that

```
NSPersistentStore *store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                     configuration:nil URL:storeURL
                                           options:options error:&error];
if (!store) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved Error");
        abort();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning and the error are two separate things.

The warning is that you are treating a pointer as if it were a number.  `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error` does not return a `BOOL` (which is essentially a number), it returns the `NSPersistentStore` object you are creating.  Instead of a boolean success variable, you should be assigning the result to an `NSPersistentStore *` variable.

In the case of failure, it returns `nil` and populates the `error` object.  You can obtain more information about the error from this object, such as logging its `localizedDescription`.

Comment: thats weird... in apples doc its `BOOL success = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:<#Store type#> configuration:<#Configuration or nil#> URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];`

Comment: it worked fine on the simulator - but i somehow fear something will go wrong with the test devices (i have 4 month of test data on them that must not be harmed, but updated to the new model..)

Comment: You're still logging a very unhelpful message.  You should log `error.localizedDescription` so if it fails, you actually have some useful information.

Comment: thanks a lot =) I added that to my project as well, now its time to cross fingers when i start updating the devices this evening =)
you were a great help, thanks.